# Can you become an emperor?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing as King of England.I have invaded the kingdom of Scotland, Wales, Portugal, half of Spain from the Muslims and part of Africa.
How can I create the British empire and become Emperor? Do I have to simply control more land or do I get the title from someone? I control about same amount of land as the Holy Roman Empire.

Comment: Plz can u be more specific. I did all that u told me I after I checked the de jure box, it only showed the duchys and republics that I control eg: duchy of Cornwall republic of kent prince- archbishopric of Lancaster etc.. Not any thing about British empire coat of arms or any thing that sort of. What do you have to do?

Comment: Yes it's clear what your saying!!The prob is there's no icon as you have marked by no 3 in your first pic. And I tried the "find title" way to but there's nothing as empire of Brittany. I'm playing in year of 1101 and I hold kingdom of Scotland, Ireland, Portugal, wales, and some five more kingdoms I don't remember the name of !! So why doesn't it show that coat of arms I did exactly what you said but still no!!!

Comment: I have for fill every requirement that have said but Paul Marshall in the comments. But still there nothin as you showed in the pics below? Y is that is there some kind of a age barrier or is it only possible in some new version or something????

Answer (score 10):

Click on the coat of arms of the kingdom of England title. You will see a check box where it says *de jure*, check that. Then, at the top right of the box, you will see a cost of arms for the *de jure* liege title of the Kingdom of England, which should be the British Empire. Click on its coat of arms. Then hover over the create button. This will tell you exactly which conditions you need to fulfill to create the title.

This button is also how you create the title and become Emperor. It will be greyed out until you meet all the conditions in the hover-over tooltip.

Here is a three-step illustration of how to find the Empire of Britannia by using the *de jure* checkbox and liege coats of arms in the Realm view:

[image: The Realm view for the Kingdom of England in 1066, with arrows pointing to the necessary controls]

Alternatively, you can always use the **Find Title** button below your world map. Click that, type part of the title you're looking for, and then it will show you matching titles in the dialogue box. Clicking a title will open the same view:

[image: Illustration of where to find the Find Title button]

The best way to learn how to use the more obscure parts of the game's interface is by playing the in-game Tutorial. It explains everything and is worth doing once.

Comment: Plz can u be more specific. I did all that u told me I after I checked the de jure box, it only showed the duchys and republics that I control eg: duchy of Cornwall republic of kent prince- archbishopric of Lancaster etc.. Not any thing about British empire coat of arms or any thing that sort of. What do you have to do?

Comment: @Rand Look up, not down. The liege is above the list of lower titles.

Comment: What do u mean by "look up" I looked every wheat over the list  there's nothing referring to what u said before. Does this have some kind of age barrier like holy orders mercenaries available after 1100 is it like that???  I couldn't find any kind of coat of arms!!! Is it maybe I'm not holding enough land but for god sake I'm the king of 7 kingdoms!!!!!  Can u give me some baby steps plz !!!!!!????

Comment: 1) Click on an English county somewhere. The information screen there has some coats-of-arms in the upper-right corner: usually county, duchy, and kingdom. Click on the rightmost coat of arms (usually kingdom) to get you to the title information screen.
2) Once you're on that screen, the middle bit has a list of titles. Look above that and to the right to see a "de jure" checkbox, and check that.
3) That changed the titles; the coats-of-arms to the upper-right of the list-of-titles box now shows titles that don't exist. The rightmost one will be for the Empire of Britannia.

Comment: 4) Click on that Empire of Britannia title (it's a red thing on a white background), and then look to the left, where there's a (probably-)grayed-out button that says "Create." Hover your mouse over that button, and it will say why you can't create it yet. You need 80% of the titles, which include England, Scotland, Ireland, Normandy (north coast of France), and Brittany (northwest of France).

Comment: @Randularipcord I added a three-step picture to make it absolutely clear, and added information on using the Find Title button as an alternative.

Comment: Yes it's clear what your saying? The prob is there's no icon as you have marked by  no 3 in your first pic. And I tryie

Comment: Is there some kind of version or age barrier ????

Comment: There is no age barrier, but version yes. Empire of Britannia was introduced in 1.06. If you have 1.06 or later, then you need to: Own 80% of the de jure holdings either directly or through vassals, and be from one of these culture groups: Celtic, Saxon, Norman, or English. See http://crusaderkings-two.wikia.com/wiki/Empire_of_Britannia

Comment: Shit I don't think I have the version 1.6 . If I'm to update how??? Will it lose my progress  in the game ?????

Comment: In any version before that is there no other way of becoming an emperor ???

Comment: In earlier versions, the only way to become emperor is to take over the title of an existing emperor: either the Byzantine Empire or the Holy Roman Empire. You want to "Request Invasion" on them in the diplomacy screen, not just "Declare War" on them; you should be Catholic, be smaller than the empire you're invading, and the Pope needs to like you more than he likes your target empire. It's also *quite hard* and not for the faint of heart; each empire has big, nasty armies.

Comment: I canot touch the Roman Empire, but the Byzantine empire is there. But the thing some one has invaded them before me but the title is still three but no ruler. Former emperor still lives he was a kid when he was the emperor but now he's no one. I think because of the civil war the nation fell apart. When I use the find title option it points me to where the old Capitol was  that's all so how to invade them????,

Comment: If there is no title holder then you can't invade them. Satisfy the conditions for creating the title and create it, that's the only way to get it now.

Answer (score 0):

The british empire is not in the base game. Do you have any of the expansion packs? If not you can only found the Byzantine empire and i think one other.

Comment: You don't need the expansions, just up-to-date patches.

Comment: I did not know that. I do not have good internet so I have not updated. Guess its time to go download them at a friends house.